# Show that there exists a $FO[\sigma]$ formula $\phi$ in Skolem form such that $\phi$ is satisfiable but $\phi$ does not have a Herbrand model

Tags: logic

Let $\sigma := \{ R,f \} $, where R is a relation with ar(R)=2 and f is a function with ar(f)=1.

I need to show that the following theorem is not valid for all FO-formulas in Skolem form, i.e. including those that contain "=".

Let $\sigma$ be a signature that contains at least one constant. For every $FO[\sigma]$ formula $\phi$ in Skolem form that does not contain an "=" sign the following holds:

$\phi$ is satifiable $\iff$ $\phi$ has a Herbrand model

So I need to show that there exists an FO[$\sigma$]-formula $\phi$ in Skolem form that contains an "=" sign, such that there exists a $\sigma$-structure A that fulfills $\rho$, but no Herbrand structure B that fulfills $\phi$.

I've never been good at existential proofs and I really don't know how to come up with a formula and a sigma structure and a Herbrand structure that function as a counter example, so can anybody help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can consider the formula:

> $\varphi := \forall x \ [(f(x) \ne x) ∧ (f(f(x)) = x)]$.

With a *constant* $c$ and the *function* symbol $f$, the Herbrand universe for $\varphi$ is $H = \{ c, f(c), f(f(c)), \ldots \}$.

The *terms* are the elements of the domain of interpretation and thus different terms, *qua* objects, are different elements of the domain.

This means that $c \ne f(c), c \ne f(f(c))$, etc. Since $\varphi$ asserts that $f(f(x)) = x$, for all $x$, we have that the sentence $\varphi$ has no Herbrand model.

But it is satisfiable in a domain $D = \{ 0, 1 \}$ with $f^D(0)=1$ and $f^D(1)=0$.